# Riot Api - Json

Tags: json

I'd love to start programming in JSON, for riot api, but I don't know how to start it.. I have done something like that, but this doesn't show anything lol.. Just white page.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>JSON example</title>
<script language="javascript" >
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/31827832?api_key=myapikey');

// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($json as $elem){
    echo $elem[0]['name'];
    echo $elem[0]['tier'];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What language are you programming in here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: It's javascript, json.

Comment: @PiotrSawicki: OK, so Javascript and JSON are not the same thing, and your code is neither of them.

Comment: I'm an idiot, ive read something wrong and I've put this code into javasript :DDD this is php code, now its wokring great, but sometimes i can't get into this page ;o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at these guides I wrote for an introduction to the Riot API and using/understanding JSON.

While you can use many languages like PHP, I teach it in Javascript/Ajax/JQuery as that knowledge than be applied to other languages pretty easily, especially with PHP since the syntax of both look decently similar.

**[[Tutorial] Beginners introduction to Riot API and JSON, using Javascript and Ajax](https://developer.riotgames.com/discussion/riot-games-api/show/kvll5V8r)**

I discuss what the API is and how you use it, as well as securing your key. I also mention JSON and how to access and understand it with a program.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: can I contact you by skype?

Comment: ive just got problem, after clicking button nothing happens. I just can't understand, this doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PiotrSawicki, Did you go to the post and look at the first tutorial?

Comment: yes, i know what was wrong i just didnt add one lane that wasn't in this tutorial

Comment: but I just can't hide my API KEY.

Comment: @PiotrSawicki your sentences are confusing me. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.